# Possible to use null layout in Android?

Tags: android

Is there an equivalent to Java's null layout in Android?  Basically I want to specify the x and y coordinates of each component and not have the layout manager choose where they go.  They will be within a scroll pane so it doesn't matter whether they fit on the screen.

I know null layouts are generally not a good idea but I have a special case where I need it.  I'm porting a Java TV guide app and the program grid is made up of JLabels.  The program dynamically generates them all, setting the x and y coords based on start/end time and channel.  Each program could start and end at any time so as far as I know a table layout won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be AbsoluteLayout, but it is now deprecated. The docs recommend using RelativeLayout or FrameLayout instead.